# AttributeError: 'Biceps' object has no attribute 'os'

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to open a saved video by using a button in tkiner, but I keep getting an error -

```
AttributeError: 'Biceps' object has no attribute 'os'
```

This is my code

```
class Biceps(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Biceps!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Menu",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Menu))

        button2.pack()



        rb1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Play", command=self.video).pack()

    def video(self):
         self.os.system("J:\Comp Project\Bicep.mp4")
```

This is the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\Comp Project\Computer Science project2 test.py", line 253, in video
    self.os.system("J:\Comp Project\Bicep.mp4")
AttributeError: 'Biceps' object has no attribute 'os'
```

Answer (score 3):

In the `video` method `self` refers to the instance of the class that the `video` method is defined on - the `Biceps` class. This class does not have an `os` attribute hence your error. If you have imported `os` in the module you should access it directly.

Try:

```
import os

...

def video(self):
    os.system("J:\Comp Project\Bicep.mp4")
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here.

```
self.os.system("J:\Comp Project\Bicep.mp4")
```

try this,

```
def video(self):
     import os
     os.system("J:\Comp Project\Bicep.mp4")
```

You are trying call a property of `Biceps` named `os`, where as you were supposed to import `os` library and call `system`.